# Pass Python list to bash/awk function

Tags: python, bash, awk

I know that it is possible to call/insert Bash/awk commands/scripts within a Python script, I found something like `os.system('''awk '[...]''')` and I suppose it works as well just for bash commands. The question is, how is it possible to pass, for instance, a Python list to these commands/this script?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's usually unnecessary,  error-prone and makes your script less portable.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you cannot. You need to produce a string from the list which the recipient can use. For example:

```
lst = ['one', 'two', 'three']
os.system("bash myscript.sh " + " ".join(lst)) #  bash myscript.sh one two three
```